# Browserify: expressions in require statements - how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I'm setting up browserify on an existing lib and one of its dependencies does something like this:

```
require('./path/to/' + module);
```

Browserify is complaining about require statements containing expressions. Given I know the exhaustive list of values the variable `module` can get assigned to, can I tell browserify to bundle those libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `bundle.require()` the modules directly server-side so long as you don't mind the warnings about expressions in `require()` printed to stderr.